# Search children by name

Tags: jquery, html

How could it be done to search for a child's div by its name comparing it by the name with a given variable's string value?

This is the idea of what i'm aming:

```
var vname="whatever";
if($("#container").children().attr('name')==vname{
    $("#container").children().attr(vname).addClass("selected");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('#container [name="' + vname + '"]').addClass('selected');
```

Or if you only want direct children:

```
$('#container > [name="' + vname + '"]').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 $("#container").children("[name="+vname+"]").addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some filters too

```
var vname="whatever";
$("#container")
    .children()
    .filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name') == vname;
    })
    .addClass("selected");
```